# how can i format the while loop syntax?

Tags: loops

I'm a beginner python learner and I wrote the following code asking a user to enter an account pin:

```
while True:
    print ('Please enter your pin.')
    pin = input()
    if pin =='2356':
        print('Access granted')
        break
```

Now... if I only want to allow the user to enter an incorrect pin 5 times before 'freezing their account', how might I do that? Am I even using the right type of loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are almost there. You can count how many times the user has input an incorrect pin by incrementing a value like the following

```
incorrect_tries = 0
while incorrect_tries <= 5:
    print ('Please enter your pin.')
    pin = input()
    if pin =='2356':
        print('Access granted')
        break
    else
        incorrect_tries +=1
```